# Laravel: Unknown type 245 sent by the server.

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a MySQL table contains `json` types. On running `Product->where('active', 1)->first();`

```
PDO::prepare(): Unknown type 245 sent by the server. Please send a report to the developers
```

I am using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a known issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/homestead-errors-2

> You could try doing "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade" to see if it's fixed in the latest version of php. There have been patches in 7.0.4 related to this at least.

Comment: I am on MAC. I also have PHP 5.6 installed. Should I downgrade it?

Comment: Which laravel version are you using? I'm also on mac but I use docker :)

Comment: Maybe you would need homebrew to upgrade it, or patch it?

Comment: I am using OSX 10.10, Laravel 5.3 and MAMP for development work.

Comment: The last supported by MAMP is `PHP 7.0.10`

Comment: I already have the required PHP and MySQL. I am rather removing JSON column altogether. Seems it could be issue for others as well.